# How can I retrieve data from only the specified fields of a mySql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a table (in a web page) containing the data from my database, but only want to display the table with fields selected by the user.  For example: I have a total of 6 fields in my table(name, email, age, location, gender, occupation).  Let's say that the user on my page selects name, email and age.  I want a table to be displayed containing all the row entries, but with only the specified fields.

This is what I've written so far but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
include("init.php");

$fields = $_POST["fields"];
$sorting = trim($_POST["sorting"]);
$filter = trim($_POST["filter"]);

$sql_query = sprintf("select * from applicants where %s order by %s", $filter, $sorting);
$query = mysql_query($sql_query);
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($query);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $field = ucfirst($field);
        echo "<th>$field</th>";
    }
echo "</tr>";

for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    while($field = mysql_fetch_field($query)) {
        if(in_array($field->name, $fields)) {
            $data = mysql_result($query, $i, $col);
            echo "<td>$data</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>false</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I thought there has an error, the function `mysql_numrows` is not exist in PHP core function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `<option>` with the value of the column name, then use this code:

```
include('init.php');

$fields = $_POST['fields'];
$sorting = trim($_POST['sorting']);
$filter = trim($_POST['filter']);

function filterFields($field) {
  if (in_array($field, array(/* Here you need to add the fields you allowed to post, to prevent attack */))) {
    return '`' . $field . '`';
  } else {
    return 'NULL';
  }
}

$escapedFields = array_map('filterFields', $fields);

// Make the query, here we use 'implode' function to join all array with ','
// Example if we have array('name', 'time'), then the function will return 'name,time'
$query = mysql_query('SELECT ' . implode(',', $escapedFields) . ' FROM `applicants` WHERE ' . $filter . ' ORDER BY ' . $sorting);
// If the query return something, then...
if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
  echo '<table border='1'>
<tr>';
  // Here we print the table header.
  for ($i = 0, $fieldsLength = sizeof($field); $i < $fieldsLength; ++$i) {
    echo '<th>' . ucfirst($fields[$i]) . '</th>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';

  // Here we print the result.
  while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $resultKeys = array_keys($result);
    for ($i = 0, $resultKeysLength = sizeof($resultKeys); $i < $resultKeysLength; ++$i) {
      echo '<td>' . $result[$resultKeys[$i]] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: This scenario is ripe for SQL injection! Always sanitize user supplied information.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to modify the

```
select * from applicants
```

sql query. The * means "all columns". Change it to:

```
$sql_query = sprintf("select `name`, `email`,`age` from applicants where %s order by %s", $filter, $sorting);
$query = mysql_query($sql_query);
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($query);
```

You can get this easily from the $_POST['fields'] variable (making sure you're escaping it!) by just:

```
"select `".implode('`,`',$escaped_fields_array)."` from applicants
```

Also, I just want to make sure that you've confirmed that the $_POST['fields'] variable was passed as an associative array (something like )

Comment: I understand that, but in my case I don't know what fields the user has selected.  I just have a $fields array variable that contains the fields that the user selected, and this array could contain 1-6 fields.

Comment: I edited the question to show you how.. also, do make sure that the $_POST['fields'] variable is an array? Test it by adding: die(print_r($_POST['fields'])) to see what prints our if you're not sure

Comment: yes the $_POST is passed in as an array.  This is how I do it.
    <select name="fields[]" multiple="yes" required>

Comment: excellent, then implosion should work fine. BTW, I edited the implosion to add backticks (`)

Comment: Also, how can I incorporate php variables into the query?  I have $filter variable that stores "age >= 23" and a $sorting variable that could contain something like "age".  How do I add this to the query so the query sorts it in that order and only returns data where the age field is >= 23.  The way I'm doing gives me this error:

     mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean    given

Comment: This means that the query is not returning a valid resource. try: $query = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error()); to see what is wrong.